# Skype keeps asking for password and recreates local account settings

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

Since 2 days skype is suddenly asking for my password whenever I start skype (despite me clickingo n save my settings). Furthermore it recreates my local account settings as if I were a first time user (thus it checks for my microphone, sound,.....).

Skype: 7.5.0.101
Windows 8.1

Despite looking around I didn't find a clue as to what is happening there and how I can correct this.

Thus my question here is what can that be?